# Adding fiscal month end

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I would like to mutate a fiscal month-end date to a dataset in R. In my company the fiscal month-end would be on 21st of that. For example

12/22/2019 to 1/21/2020 will be Jan-2020
1/22/2020 to 2/21/2020 will be Feb-2020
2/22/2020 to 3/21/2020 will be Mar-2020
etc

Dataset

[image]

Desired_output

[image]

How would I accomplish this in R. The Date column in my data is %m/%d/%Y(1/22/2020)

Comment: Please add first few rows of your data using `dput` and show expected output for that. `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: @RonakShah just added

Comment: Please see the instructions for posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page. If you post images then no one can use the data except by tediously retyping it.  Showing the output of `dput(x)` or `dput(head(x))` in your question avoids this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the date and if date is greater than 22 add 10 days to it and get the date in month-year format :

```
transform(dat, Fiscal_Month = format(Date + 
               ifelse(as.integer(format(Date, '%d')) >= 22, 10, 0), '%b %Y'))

#        Date Fiscal_Month
#1 2020-01-20     Jan 2020
#2 2020-01-21     Jan 2020
#3 2020-01-22     Feb 2020
#4 2020-01-23     Feb 2020
#5 2020-01-24     Feb 2020
```

This can also be done without `ifelse` like this :

```
transform(dat, Fiscal_Month = format(Date + c(0, 10)
                        [(as.integer(format(Date, '%d')) >= 22) + 1], '%b %Y'))
```

**data**

Used this sample data :

```
dat <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-20'), by = '1 day',length.out = 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) yearmon** We perform the following steps:

- create test data `d` which shows both a date in the start of period month (i.e. 22nd or later) and a date in the end of period month (i.e. 21st or earlier)
- convert the input `d` to `Date` class giving `dd`
- subtract 21 days thereby shifting it to the month that starts the fiscal period
- convert that to `ym` of `yearmon` class (which represents a year and a month without a day directly and internally represents it as the year plus 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec) and then add 1/12 to get to the month at the end of fiscal period.
- format it as shown.  (We could omit this step, i.e. the last line of code, if the default format, e.g. Jan 2020, that `yearmon` uses is ok.

The whole thing could easily be written in a single line of code but we have broken it up for clarity.

```
library(zoo)

d <- c("1/22/2020", "1/21/2020") # test data

dd <- as.Date(d, "%m/%d/%Y")
ym <- as.yearmon(dd - 21) + 1/12
format(ym, "%b-%y")
## [1] "Feb-20" "Jan-20"
```

**2) Base R** This could be done using only in base R as follows.  We make use of `dd` from above.  `cut` computes the first of the month that `dd-21` lies in (but not as a `Date` class object) and then `as.Date` converts it to one.  Adding 31 shifts it to the end of period month and formatting this we get the final answer.

```
format(as.Date(cut(dd - 21, "month")) + 31, "%b-%y")
## [1] "Feb-20" "Jan-20"
```